# A summation with Stirling numbers of the Second kind

Tags: combinatorics, summation, stirling-numbers

Can the following sum be evaluated?

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-k}\left( n-k\right)
!S\left( n,n-k\right) \left( \frac{k-1}{k}\right) ^{k}$$

where $S(n,m)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

use :

$$n^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{n-k}\left(n-k\right)!{n\brace n-k}$$
And observe that ${n\brace 0}=0$ for $n>0$

Comment: Yes, I know this relation but how one can use this relation as there is additional term (function of k) multiplied.